# Lightning network: funds into channels

Tags: lightning-network, funds, ln-opening-channels

Is there a minimum limit of bitcoin that can be added into a channel during the initialization?

And, if I decided to open a channel with a lightning node, also that node has to add money to the channel?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a minimum limit of bitcoin that can be added into a channel
>   during the initialization?

According to the [Lightning Network Specifications](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#commitment-transaction-outputs):

"*The amounts for each output MUST be rounded down to whole satoshis. If this amount, **minus the fees** for the HTLC transaction, is less than the **dust_limit_satoshis** set by the owner of the commitment transaction, the output MUST NOT be produced (thus the funds add to fees).*"

So, the commitment must be greater than the sum of the transaction fee (determined by miners at the time of broadcast) and the `dust_limit_satoshis` value. The dust limit purpose is "*to prevent creation of uneconomic outputs (which would otherwise remain forever, unspent on the blockchain*." - [BOLT #5](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/4aabe6052395269f82e20b06f1e6b717c343f7d9/05-onchain.md#rationale-1)

> And, if I decided to open a channel with a lightning node, also that
>   node has to add money to the channel?

From what I understand, this is not typical, but it depends on your agreement with that other node. "*Initially they each hold a bitcoin transaction that sends all the bitcoin (e.g. 0.1 bitcoin) back to one party.*" [Lightning RFC - Introductions](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/00-introduction.md#channels). So, if the fundee needed to make a payment to the funder, it could provide a payment up front.

Comment: I believe that as of the current implementations of lnd, the default, tested and only way is to open a channel when only the initiate party funds the channel. That is to answer your second question. I’ll be happy to know if there any development with this issue.

Comment: Perhaps initialization is a special case, since there are no previous commitments that one can try to commit fraud with. For all subsequent cases (after the counterparty has more than 1% of the funds), there are more things to consider: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/80731/minimum-funds-required-in-a-channel-in-lightning/80786#80786